# Is the Nepal Tourism Board in Bhrikutimandap, Kathmandu, open on Saturdays?

Tags: nepal, kathmandu

I need to get a TIMS card from the Nepal Tourism Board on Saturday. But I am getting conflicting information. On the [official site](https://www.welcomenepal.com/plan-your-trip/tims-card.html) I have found:

> TIMS Counter office hours at Tourist Service Center, Bhrikutimandap, Kathmandu, are from 10 am to 5 pm, 7 days a week.

But Google Maps and Facebook say that this place is closed on Saturday. Maybe someone was there on Saturday and has this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have been there and I can confirm - it is open on Saturdays.